# Javascript alert popup form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i have search this whole site and google but cannot find it so, here goes!

i would like a way to show a form when using alert.

for example, when user click post, a dialog pop with asking user a few question like a html form and allow user to click submit or reset or cancel, without loading a new page.

i have seen this done but cannot find the same site again.

i have tried putting htm  to alert with little success of posting.

any Help is Highly Appreciated!

Comment: Its still not clear what you want to achieve. Please elaborate your question more or show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is a Prompt Box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_prompt() {
        var name = prompt('Please enter your name','Poppy');
        if (name != null && name != "") {
            alert(name);
        }
    }
</script>
```

<sub>example taken from here:  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp</sub>

Comment: Can we provide facility of Select list by any chance.??

Comment: @KhushalDave I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I meant if we can add Select option on the prompt box. Thanks

Comment: @KhushalDave If you want to do something more complicated than a simple prompt, you'll need to implement it yourself, or grab a library for it.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with jQuery dialogs -- load the dialog on user click and have a form presented in the dialog. have a look at the demos here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 2):

To complete @Liv's answer you can use jQuery's UI 
Reference: [`Modal Form`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

The example shows how to create a new user. It will pop up a dialog where you complete a form and you can submit it or you can cancel it.

> *Use a **modal dialog** to require that the user enter data during a multi-step process. Embed form markup in the content area, set the modal option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions with the buttons option.*

It pretty much what I understood you need.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

HTML can't be placed in system dialogs generated by `alert()`, `confirm()` or `prompt()`. However, you can download [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download) and set it up on your Website. (Make sure you have the "dialog" component chosen on the download page.) Then in your JavaScript:

```
$("<div>Place your HTML here</div>").appendTo("body").dialog({
     modal: true,
     title: "Enter a title here"
});
```

Make sure you run this code **after** the page has loaded by using either `window.onload` or `$(document).ready()`.

Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this with `alert`, but you should take a look at how to create [modal windows](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript%20modal%20window).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a div popup. What you have to do is setting a background on top of all other elements except the div where your form is. The css property display will be set to 'none' until the form is then activated, by setting display = "block". That can be performed using javascript.