# Make Javascript bookmark click a button in certain conditions

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarks

I need to bookmark a JavaScript function that, in certain conditions, should click a button on a webpage.

Right now, I have a bookmark saying "Hello..."

```
javascript:(function (){ alert('Hello ...'); })();
```

Instead of "hello..." I would like to have an HTML form with with 3 checkboxes and if all these 3 checkboxes are ticked, to automatically click a button on the webpage.

I'm not sure how I can include these functions into an alert box.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227507/javascript-alert-popup-form

Comment: I didn't understand the issue. You need a `function` which will trigger another `function` when 3 checkboxes in an HTML form with are checked.
Is it so?

Comment: I misspelled it. Its just one function that pop-s up 3 checkboxes on the users screen. Once all these checkboxes are ticked, a button (ID=submit) on the webpage is pressed automatically by the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in simple alert box.
Consider using a modal window from 3rd party (ex. bootstrap modal: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or implement your own like described here: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Just for simple confirm dialog:

```
<button id="targetBtn" onclick="alert('Target Button click')">Target Button</button>
<button onclick="if (window.confirm('Do you really want to click Target Button?')){document.getElementById('targetBtn').click();}">Click me</button>
```

Comment: It's not necessary to be an Alert. It can be a prompt as well. Or anything else that pop's up on the users screen

Comment: I dont think a modal will work, as it needs heavy CSS styling. And I need to  include this into a bookmark (link location field) in the browser

Comment: A prompt dialog contains only one single-line textbox and OK/Cancel buttons. So it's not possible.

Comment: @Vishera you can't popup checkboxes without modals.

Comment: What about the 2nd part of the request, to make it without the checkboxes, just to display a message and after hitting OK, to automatically press a button on the webpage?